# Create a new div element when button is clicked JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a div element when a button is clicked and then put things such as an h1 element in that div.

Something like this:

```js
function submit() {
  var card = document.createElement("div");
  card.innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: you created it, you did not add it to the document.  Add more elements to it? More createElement lines or innerHTML with elements.

Comment: ok so how do i add it that's what I'm asking.

Comment: LIke in the MDN documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: you can edit your submit function to be this:
let submit = _=> document.body.innerHTML += "<div><h1>Hello</h1></div>";

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `append()` or `appendChild()` methods like this:

```js
function submit() {
  var card = document.createElement("div");
  card.innerHTML = "Hello";
  
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  h1.innerHTML = "Some h1 text";
  
  card.append(h1);
  document.body.append(card); 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use submit as a function name or call a button submit if it isn't an actual submit input for a form.

You need to append the node you created to the dom.

```js
function pushMe() {
  var card = document.createElement("div");
  card.innerHTML = "<h1>Hello</h1>";
  
  var element = document.getElementById("here");
element.appendChild(card);
}
```

```html
<div id='here'>
<button onclick="pushMe()">pushMe</button>
</div>
```